# Cannot :Explore public ftp service (I see empty listing with ../ and ./)

Tags: netrw

The address is ftp://ftp.yandex.ru/

I tried from bash:
`vim ftp://ftp.yandex.ru/`

After that I was asked for username and password (but this is public anonymous server), ok I entered `anonymous` for username and password. I tried to "enter" empty username and password also. I see this:

```
" ============================================================================
" Netrw Directory Listing                                        (netrw v156)
"   ftp://ftp.yandex.ru/
"   Sorted by      name
"   Sort sequence: [\/]$,\<core\%(\.\d\+\)\=\>,\.h$,\.c$,\.cpp$,\~\=\*$,*,\.o$,\.obj$,\.info$,\.swp$,\.bak$,\~$
"   Quick Help: <F1>:help  -:go up dir  D:delete  R:rename  s:sort-by  x:special
" ==============================================================================
../
./
```

Vim 8 from default repository on Xubuntu 18.04.3 LTS.

Comment: `anonymous` for username and password works for me (Vim 8, Ubuntu 18.04.3)

Comment: @muru trued again - the same empty screen of explorer.

Comment: Does your network block access to that site or to FTP? Can you access it using the command-line `ftp` client, or a browser?

Comment: @muru I can open this link in Firefox.

Comment: As well as seeing the behaviour you describe, netrw also opens a split window containing a `NetrwMessage` buffer with the contents: `**error** (netrw) this system doesn't support remote directory listing via ftp` ...which clearly isn't true.